# AngularJS and Spring MVC login error

Tags: angularjs

```js
var appModule = angular.module('myApp', [ 'angular-storage', 'ui.router' ]);

appModule
  .controller(
    'MainCtrl',
    [
      'mainService','$scope','$http','userFactory','$state','$rootScope','store',
      function(mainService, $scope, $http, userFactory, $state,$rootScope,store) {
       
       $scope.token = null;
       $scope.error = null;
       $scope.user={"emailId":"","password":""};

       $scope.login = function(user) {
        $scope.error = null;
        mainService
          .login(user)
          .then(
            function(token) {
            
             $scope.token = token;
             $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer '
               + token;
             userFactory.setUserToken(token);
             console.log("token store");

             $state.go("home");
            }, function(error) {
             $scope.error = error
             $scope.userName = '';
             alert("not");
            });
       }

       

       

       $scope.loggedIn = function() {

        return store.get("token") !== null;
       }
       
       
      
       
      } ]);


appModule.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','mainService','$http','userFactory','$state',function($scope,mainService,$http,userFactory,$state){
 $scope.greeting = 'Welcome to the JSON Web Token / AngularJR / Spring example!';
 $scope.roleUser = false;
 $scope.roleAdmin = false;
 $scope.roleFoo = false;
// $scope.checkRoles = function() {
 mainService.hasRole('user').then(
   function(user) {
    console.log(user + " user");
    $scope.roleUser = user
   });
 mainService.hasRole('admin').then(
   function(admin) {
    console.log(admin + " admin");
    $scope.roleAdmin = admin
   });
 mainService.hasRole('foo').then(function(foo) {
  $scope.roleFoo = foo
 });
// }
 
 $scope.logout = function() {
  $scope.userName = '';
  $scope.token = null;
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
  userFactory.removeUserToken();
  $state.go("login");
 }
 
}]);


appModule.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
   $stateProvider.state('login', {
    url : "/login",
    templateUrl : "login.html",
    controller : 'MainCtrl'

   }).state('home', {
    url : "/home",
    templateUrl : "home.html",
    controller : 'HomeCtrl'
   });
  } ]);

appModule.config([ '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');

} ]);

appModule.factory('myInterceptor', function(store,userFactory) {
 var myInterceptor = {
  request : function(request) {
   if(userFactory.getUserToken() !=null){
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ userFactory.getUserToken();
    return request;
   }
   return request;
  },
  response : function(response) {
   
   return response;
  }

 };
 return myInterceptor;
});

appModule.run(function(mainService,$state,$rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
   var is=mainService.auth();
   if(is == false && next.name=="home"){
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go("login");
   }
  
  });

});



appModule.factory('userFactory',['store',function(store){
 
 var user={};
 
 user.setUserToken=function(token){
  store.set("token",token);
 },
 
 user.getUserToken=function(){
  return store.get("token");
 },
 
 user.removeUserToken=function(){
  store.remove("token");
 }
 
 return user;
 
 
 
}]);



appModule.service('mainService', function($http, userFactory) {
 return {
  login : function(user) {
            
            var config={
                method:'POST',
                url:'http://192.168.0.5:8080/TeamAssist/camelRestlet/getLoginDetails?restletMethod=post'
            };
            
            return $http(config, user).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
                return response.data.token;
   });
  },

  hasRole : function(role) {
   return $http.get('/api/role/' + role).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response.data;
   });
  },
  auth : function() {
   if (userFactory.getUserToken() == null)
    return false;
   else
    return true;
  }

 };
});var appModule = angular.module('myApp', [ 'angular-storage', 'ui.router' ]);

appModule
  .controller(
    'MainCtrl',
    [
      'mainService','$scope','$http','userFactory','$state','$rootScope','store',
      function(mainService, $scope, $http, userFactory, $state,$rootScope,store) {
       
       $scope.token = null;
       $scope.error = null;
       $scope.user={"emailId":"","password":""};

       $scope.login = function(user) {
        $scope.error = null;
        mainService
          .login(user)
          .then(
            function(token) {
            
             $scope.token = token;
             $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer '
               + token;
             if(token.length<=10)
                                                    {
                                                        $scope.token = '';
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
                                                        $state.go('login');
                                                        return;
                                                    }
             userFactory.setUserToken(token);
             console.log("token store");

             $state.go("home");
            }, function(error) {
             $scope.error = error
             $scope.userName = '';
             alert("not");
            });
       }

       

       

       $scope.loggedIn = function() {

        return store.get("token") !== null;
       }
       
       
      
       
      } ]);


appModule.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','mainService','$http','userFactory','$state',function($scope,mainService,$http,userFactory,$state){
 $scope.greeting = 'Welcome to the JSON Web Token / AngularJR / Spring example!';
 $scope.roleUser = false;
 $scope.roleAdmin = false;
 $scope.roleFoo = false;
// $scope.checkRoles = function() {
 mainService.hasRole('user').then(
   function(user) {
    console.log(user + " user");
    $scope.roleUser = user
   });
 mainService.hasRole('admin').then(
   function(admin) {
    console.log(admin + " admin");
    $scope.roleAdmin = admin
   });
 mainService.hasRole('foo').then(function(foo) {
  $scope.roleFoo = foo
 });
// }
 
 $scope.logout = function() {
  $scope.userName = '';
  $scope.token = null;
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
  userFactory.removeUserToken();
  $state.go("login");
 }
 
}]);


appModule.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
   $stateProvider.state('login', {
    url : "/login",
    templateUrl : "login.html",
    controller : 'MainCtrl'

   }).state('home', {
    url : "/home",
    templateUrl : "home.html",
    controller : 'HomeCtrl'
   });
  } ]);

appModule.config([ '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');

} ]);

appModule.factory('myInterceptor', function(store,userFactory) {
 var myInterceptor = {
  request : function(request) {
   if(userFactory.getUserToken() !=null){
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ userFactory.getUserToken();
    return request;
   }
   return request;
  },
  response : function(response) {
   
   return response;
  }

 };
 return myInterceptor;
});

appModule.run(function(mainService,$state,$rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
   var is=mainService.auth();
   if(is == false && next.name=="home"){
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go("login");
   }
  
  });

});



appModule.factory('userFactory',['store',function(store){
 
 var user={};
 
 user.setUserToken=function(token){
  store.set("token",token);
 },
 
 user.getUserToken=function(){
  return store.get("token");
 },
 
 user.removeUserToken=function(){
  store.remove("token");
 }
 
 return user;
 
 
 
}]);



appModule.service('mainService', function($http, userFactory) {
 return {
  login : function(user) {
            
            var config={
                method:'GET',
                url:'http://192.168.0.64:8080/TeamAssist/rest/service/login/'+ user.emailId + '/' + user.password,
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }
  
            };
            
            return $http(config, user).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
                return response.data;
   });
  },

  hasRole : function(role) {
   return $http.get('/api/role/' + role).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response.data;
   });
  },
  auth : function() {
   if (userFactory.getUserToken() == null)
    return false;
   else
    return true;
  }

 };
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form ng-submit="login(user)">
  Username: <input type="text" ng-model="user.emailId" /><br/>
        Password: <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" /><span><input
   type="submit" value="Login" />
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

After successfully login and logout, when I do login again with correct credentials, I got "****Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers**.**" error, but if  I refresh the page then I get successfully logged-IN.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. To get constructive answers please be sure to [provide enough details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It probably relates to your server configuration. What the error suggests is your http headers lacks Access-Control-Allow-Headers